# Checkboxlist in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I'm very new in asp.net core. How to create checkbox list in asp.net core? As the example, the list displays the course and student can choose the course that they interest.

Comment: I would suggest that to will read a basic tutorial about asp.net core. In which technology you will make the client? Asp.net mvc or for example angular?Your question no specific enough

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a complete example of how to use checkboxes in ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Core**

**Model :**

```
public class Student
    {
        public Student()
        {
            Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
        }
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Student Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    }

public class Course
    {
        public Course()
        {
            Students = new HashSet<Student>();
        }
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Course Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }

    }
```

**Controller:**

```
    public class StudentsController : Controller
            {
                private readonly CheckBoxListDbConetxt _dbConetxt = new CheckBoxListDbConetxt();


        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult CreateStudent()
                {

                    ViewBag.AllCourses = _dbConetxt.Courses.ToList();
                    return View();
                }

                // POST: Students/Create
                [HttpPost]
                [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
                public IActionResult CreateStudent(Student student, List<int> selectedCourses)
                {
                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        if (selectedCourses != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var item in selectedCourses)
                            {
                                Course course = _dbConetxt.Courses.Find(item);
                                student.Courses.Add(course);
                            }
                        }

                        _dbConetxt.Students.Add(student);
                        _dbConetxt.SaveChanges();
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }

                    ViewBag.AllCourses = _dbConetxt.Courses.ToList();
                    return View(student);
                }
}
```

**In View:**

```
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-2 input-label">
                <label class="control-label">Course</label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-10 input-box">
                <div class="form-control">
                    @{
                        var count = Enumerable.Count(ViewBag.AllCourses);
                        foreach (var item in ViewBag.AllCourses)
                        {
                            <input type="checkbox" name="selectedCourses" value="@item.Id" />
                            @item.Name
                            if (--count > 0)
                            {
                                @:|
                        }
                        }
                    }

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the browser render a checkbox you need an  elements of type checkbox:

```
<input id="checkBox" name="checkbox" type="checkbox">
```

To create a list of checkbox items you simply render multiple of those elements.

Asp.net core simplifies this by allowing you to express your loop using the razor syntax. You can put the following in your cshtml file to render e.g. 10 checkbox items:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <br />
}
```

Finally you can make use of an Asp.net Tag Helper to further ease the creation of the required html.

The example assumes you have a model called Student which has a property IsEnrolled.

```
@model Student

@for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
        <input asp-for="IsEnrolled" />
        <br />
}
```

Due to the use of the input tag helper (asp-for) the html which is rendered to browser automatically includes the id and name HTML attributes. What is more the tag helper automatically sets the type=checkbox by evaluating the underlying data type of the IsEnrolled property.

Answer (score -2):

```
  <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>Electronics</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Electricals</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Civil</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Mechanical</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Comment: op meant asp.net core